# GXT Panels with min height and scrollbar if the resolution is so small

Tags: gwt, gxt

We have a projet with GXT 3, it was designed for resolution 1920 x 1080.
But we will have somme user with resolution 1366 X 768.

The application is build in full page with a BorderLayoutContainer which fit all the navigator window size.

How to add the center layout countainer in a Panel with a min height and width ?
If the resolution is big, the center container just fit the navigator size. But if the resolution is less than the min size, the container is in a scroll area.

Is there a GXT widget for doing this option ? I don't find any widget with a setMinWidth()

Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GWT control called "ScrollPanel" where you have a panel or container of fixed height and width. For example,

```
<gxt:Window ui:field="window" modal="true" closable="true" onEsc="true" width="850" collapsible="true" resizable="true" maximizable="true" draggable="true" height="600" shadow="true">
    <g:ScrollPanel>
             <gxt:FramedPanel..../>
    </g:ScrollPanel>
</gxt:window>
```

This enables scrolling for a modal with fixed height and width. I believe it can also be used when window size changes. However, in this example, the scroll panel enables scrolling for the framed panel. But it can be used anywhere wrapping.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I now the GWT ScrollPanel, but the FramedPanel must have a fixed height for the scroll to be displayed.
If the screen resolution is heighter than 800px, the Panel must be proportionnel of the navigator height.
If the screan resolution is less than 800px, the panel must have a scroll and have a fixed heigth.

Comment: I am still working on it. Couldn't figure out yet. Lemme know if you find a solution.